# How to downgrade MagickCore

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install [imgtxtenh](https://github.com/mauvilsa/imgtxtenh), but keep running into this error:

```
-- Checking for module 'MagickCore>=6.7.7'
--   Found MagickCore, version 7.1.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (message):
  MagickCore 7 or newer not supported!
```

I built ImageMagick 6.9.12-19 from source but that didn't have any effect.

I posted this on Stack Overflow initially before it was closed for being a software/hardware question instead of programming related. Someone suggested "Remove the alien version 7.1.0 ." But I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas?